# Running riak nodes as cluster on different ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, riak

I have setted up riak in two seperate instances and the nodes are up. Also I am able additional nodes in the same machine and do clustering.
I am stuck here joining a node on the other instance. Below are steps I have followed.

- stopped riak
- changed nodename in riak.conf and assigned **private ips** of my instances in vm.args and app.config
   changed node name nodename = riak@172.31.18.146
   changed listener.http.internal to  = 0.0.0.0:8098
   changed listener.protobuf.internal to = 0.0.0.0:8087
- deleted ring folder
- started riak
- tried joining to another node, but failed with response
  Node riak@172.31.28.150 is not reachable!

Hope someoone had this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Joe for the pointing  out the issue.Erlang use some other ports as well. My security rules look like as in below.
[image]

Now I am able to form cluster between instance nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure connections are permitted between the nodes on port 4369-EPMD, and the distribution port range 6000-7999.

See the docs at http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/building/installing/aws-marketplace/ for more detail

Comment: THanks Joe. Issue was with the port opening for ec2 instances.